# Add numbers from inside a loop to display total outside. Java

Tags: java, loops, addition

I am wondering how to display the total number of rainfall that I took in from user input and add them outside of the loop. This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SecretName {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int year;
    int rain;
    int count = 0;
    String[]names={"January ","February "};


    System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
    year= keyboard.nextInt();

    while (count < year) {


        System.out.println("For year "+ count);


        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter the inches of rainfall for "+ names[i]+":");
            rain= keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        count++;

    }
    int numMonths = names.length * year;
    System.out.println("Number of months "+ numMonths);
    System.out.println("Total rainfall "+ rain); //Won't work obviously


}
}
```

I have everything I need it's just I take in the rainfall, but I don't know how to add all the rains I take in and add them to be displayed outside the loop where I have the line down there.
I have a feeling I'm just over looking something simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your variables with 0 and do what @Juned Ahsan said

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SecretName {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int year = 0;
    int rain = 0;
    int count = 0;
String[]names={"January ","February "};


System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
year= keyboard.nextInt();

while (count < year) {


    System.out.println("For year "+ count);


    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the inches of rainfall for "+ names[i]+":");
        rain += keyboard.nextInt(); // Is the same as rain = rain + keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    count++;

}
int numMonths = names.length * year;
System.out.println("Number of months "+ numMonths);
System.out.println("Total rainfall "+ rain);


}
}
```

Comment: Just as I thought...It was so simple that couldn't see it.  Thanks man I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you just need to replace this:

```
        rain= keyboard.nextInt();
```

with

```
        rain += keyboard.nextInt();
```

Comment: Gives me an error when I add the + to it as you said. Not sure that'd be correct unless your aware of something I ain't.